# Bold Font settings for TODO keywords in org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have added a NEXT todo keyword using the below setting

```
(setq org-todo-keywords
  '((sequence "TODO(t)" "NEXT(n)" "|" "DONE(d!/!)")))
```

I want to change the "NEXT" todo keyword font setting color to cyan and bold, i have used the following to set this up.

```
(setq org-todo-keyword-faces
  '(("NEXT" . (:foreground "cyan" :bold t))))
```

The color gets changed but the "NEXT" keyword font is not displayed in bold as the "TODO" keyword gets displayed. How to make it to bold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

how about this.?

```
(setq org-todo-keyword-faces
  (quote (("NEXT" :foreground "cyan" :weight bold))))
```