# Add custom markers to emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm using emacs org-mode for various purposes. Most common functionality is to mark my tasks with special tags `TODO` & `DONE`. Is there a way to add custom tags (e.g `IN_PROGRESS`) and highlight it with separate color?

Also, would be good, if this tag roll in the same buffer as `TODO` and `DONE` so I can switch between them by using the same hotkeys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bold Font settings for TODO keywords in org-mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861109/bold-font-settings-for-todo-keywords-in-org-mode)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I use the following in my init.el, which sets additional task statuses and their styles for all org files:

```
(setq org-todo-keyword-faces
      '(
        ("NOT-TODO" . (:foreground "blue" :weight bold))
        ("IF-TIME" . (:foreground "yellow" :weight bold))
        ("NOT-REPRO" . (:foreground "purple" :weight bold))
        ))

(setq org-todo-keywords
      '((sequence "TODO" "NOT-TODO" "NOT-REPRO" "IF-TIME" "DONE")))
```

Comment: Thanks! What do you use NOT-TODO for; why not just remove the keyword?

Comment: @SamHasler, `NOT-TODO` is a little like `WONTFIX`, indicating a resolved action item (as opposed to a headline that was never marked for action).  I originally started using it when working with testers who were submitting issues that sometimes ended up conflicting with other requirements or constraints.  I now use it in my own projects before archiving an item that I changed my mind about, especially if I clocked any time to it.  It should always include an explanation, and I now use it with `(@)` so that I get prompted for a note when setting it.

Answer (score 15):

You can do as this in the beginning of the file:

```
#+TODO: TODO IN-PROGRESS WAITING DONE
```

Press C-c C-c on that line to refresh the setup (not needed for subsequent loads of the file), and everything should be jolly.

As explained [here](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org4beginners.html).

Answer (score 15):

I use the following to produce TODO keywords that look a little like buttons to make them stand out more clearly in my outlines and agenda. This styling came from the mailing list if my memory serves me.

```
  (setq org-todo-keywords
  '((sequence "TODO"
      "MAYBE"
      "NEXT"
      "STARTED"
      "WAITING"
      "DELEGATED"
      "|"
      "DONE"
      "DEFERRED"
      "CANCELLED")))

  (setq org-todo-keyword-faces
    '(("PROJ" :background "blue" :foreground "black" :weight bold :box (:line-width 2 :style released-button))
      ("TODO" :background "red1" :foreground "black" :weight bold :box (:line-width 2 :style released-button))
      ("NEXT" :background "red1" :foreground "black" :weight bold :box (:line-width 2 :style released-button))
      ("STARTED" :background "orange" :foreground "black" :weight bold :box (:line-width 2 :style released-button))
      ("WAITING" :background "yellow" :foreground "black" :weight bold :box (:line-width 2 :style released-button))
      ("DEFERRED" :background "gold" :foreground "black" :weight bold :box (:line-width 2 :style released-button))
      ("DELEGATED" :background "gold" :foreground "black" :weight bold :box (:line-width 2 :style released-button))
      ("MAYBE" :background "gray" :foreground "black" :weight bold :box (:line-width 2 :style released-button))
      ("APPT" :background "red1" :foreground "black" :weight bold :box (:line-width 2 :style released-button))
      ("DONE" :background "forest green" :weight bold :box (:line-width 2 :style released-button))
      ("CANCELLED" :background "lime green" :foreground "black" :weight bold :box (:line-width 2 :style released-button))))
```

This makes my agenda look like the following:
[image]

Comment: I've started using your keywords and faces, here is a snippet so that my old file-specific states will still be in your style: `(set-face-attribute 'org-todo nil
                    :background "red1"
                    :foreground "black"
                    :weight 'bold
                    :box '(:line-width 2 :style released-button))`. If I find any `DONE` states left over, I can fix similarly with `(set-face-attribute 'org-done ...`.

Answer (score 5):

To add keywords without modifying the specific org file you can modify `org-todo-keywords`.

See [the org manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/TODO-types.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the fine-grained

```
(setq org-todo-keyword-faces
      '(...
       )
```

which allows you to make adjustments to every `TODO` state, you might consider a dichotomy approach, which essentially make one face for each of the two groups on either side of the `|` pipe, for instance

```
(set-face-attribute 'org-todo nil
                    :foreground "#AFD8AF"
                    )
(set-face-attribute 'org-done nil
                    :foreground "#CC9393"
                    )
```

(This color choice is my current switch in `zenburn` theme.) That is, these apply respectively for the groups in

```
TODO1 TODO2 ... TODOk | DONE1 DONE2 ... DONEn
```

So for instance, [image]

---

ETA:

I've since had to wrestle with the fact that various org-mode headline levels have various colorings, and it was too inconvenient to try to find color pairs (for `org-todo` and `org-done`) that would contrast nicely with all headline levels. Further, would have to deal with changing Emacs' color-themes, as the low contrast zenburn may be less appropriate as the season changes.

It is much easier to simply invert the default colors. The resulting rectangle edge is a little awkward, so the border helps to make it look a little more natural. Then, I arrive at a scheme much like Stuart Hickinbottom's.

So I now have

```
(set-face-attribute 'org-todo nil
                    :box '(:line-width 2 
                           :color "grey75" 
                           :style released-button)
                    :inverse-video t
                    )
(set-face-attribute 'org-done nil
                    :box '(:line-width 2 
                           :color "grey75" 
                           :style released-button)
                    :inverse-video t
                    )
(set-face-attribute 'org-priority nil
                    :inherit font-lock-keyword-face 
                    :inverse-video t 
                    :box '(:line-width 2 
                           :color "grey75" 
                           :style released-button)
                    )
```

This produces, with init file color choice `(load-theme 'deeper-blue t)`,

[image]

(Red as in STOP! Do this! Green as in you are free to go and play.)